# BUILD FAILED when trying to build apk with crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am trying to get started with crosswalk, so I looked at their documentation and followed all the necessary steps. But when I am trying to run the command:

```
python make_apk.py --package=org.crosswalkproject.example     --manifest=tasker/manifest.json
```

I get an error, at first everything is good but then there is a BUILD ERROR:

```
Checking manifest file
Checking system requirements...ok

Starting application build (x86)
 * Checking keystore for signing
   No keystore provided for signing. Using xwalk's keystore for debugging.
   Please use a valid keystore when distributing to the app market.
 * Updating project with xwalk_core_library
 * Checking for external extensions
 * Copying native libraries for x86
 * Building Android apk package with Crosswalk embedded (x86)

BUILD FAILED
/home/user1/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user1/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user1/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 127

Total time: 0 seconds
Command "/home/user1/Documents/ant/bin/ant release -f /tmp/Example-zZk3z9/build.xml -Dkey.store=/home/user1/Documents/crosswalk-10.39.235.15/xwalk-debug.keystore -Dkey.alias=xwalkdebugkey -Dkey.store.password=xwalkdebug -Dkey.alias.password=xwalkdebug" exited with non-zero exit code 1
```

I suppose that it is something to do with the alias code, but I am not sure.

P.S my **index.html and manifest.json** are just like the ones in the tutorial. 
I followed every step.
This is the doc I am following: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started.html
Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Do you manage to compile regular cordova app? What are you trying to compile, a cordova-crosswalk app or pure crosswalk app? (maybe provide a link to what doc exactly you're following)

Comment: I added now the link to the doc. Right now I am trying to comple a pure crosswalk app, but later I would like to add cordova api's to my app also.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the android tools. That's why I asked if you manage to build regular android apps with cordova. If you have installed cordova, maybe could you try the check_recqs.sh to see what it tells (should be somewhere in ~/.cordova/lib/android)

Comment: I didn't install cordova, yet.
I am trying to get a simple application to run at first.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest you double-check the steps about installing Android SDK. Platform from within the SDK manager. If you have and it still does not work, try installing a version more recent than what's listed in the doc. I have like SDK platworm 21, SDK Tools 24 and Platform tools 21 and I successfully build cordova crosswalk apps.

Comment: And if it still does not work, check what's at line 698 of /home/user1/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml

Comment: I am also having same error with my application but I don't know what the sollution

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem.

I did a little research and it looks like there could be many different causes for this error.

In my case I had to install "lib32stdc++6"

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

You can find out more about the problem you have by using

```
--verbose
```

when you run the make_apk.py

For other people it was mix of different target versions in the build xmls which caused the problem.